# Replace text in file with user input containing space, using sed

Tags: linux, replace, sed

My script:

```
#!/bin/sh

cp -f host.tpl host.conf
mkdir -p /var/www/$1

server_replace="s,{server_name},$1,g"
sed -i $server_replace host.conf

alias_replace="s,{server_alias},$2,g"
sed -i $alias_replace host.conf
```

File in which i'm doing replacemants (vhost.tpl):

```
<VirtualHost 0.0.0.0:80>
    ServerName {server_name}
    ServerAlias {server_alias}
    DocumentRoot /var/www/{server_name}
</VirtualHost>
```

It works fine when I'm creating vhost with one server alias

```
./vhost.sh domain.com www.domain.com
```

But when I want to have more aliases

```
./vhost.sh domain.com "www.domain.com m.domain.com"
```

script fails with message like

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 31: unterminated `s' command
```

Do I have to escape space character in some way to use it in replacement string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put a pair of double quotes around the `$alias_replace` reference:

```
sed -i.bkp "$alias_replace" host.conf
```

It should do the trick. You just need to do it in the second sed call but I would strongly suggest you tho quote both variables.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -i -e "s,{server_name},$1,g" -e "s,{server_alias},$2,g" host.conf
```

No need for two commands.  Every need to use the double quotes.

You could avoid the `-e` options if you wanted to; I find them clearer than the alternative.